# Extract shortcode from Instagram URL

Tags: php, regex

I try to extract the shortcode from Instagram URL

Here what i have already tried but i don't know how to extract when they are an username in the middle. Thank you a lot for your answer.

Instagram pattern : /p/shortcode/

https://regex101.com/r/nO4vdd/1/

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/BxKRx5CHn5i/
https://www.instagram.com/p/BxKRx5CHn5i/?utm_source=ig_share_sheet&igshid=znsinsart176
https://www.instagram.com/p/BxKRx5CHn5i/
https://www.instagram.com/username/p/BxKRx5CHn5i/

expected : BxKRx5CHn5i
```

Comment: For the information of anyone who might read your question, are there any rules regarding what the Instagram shortcodes look like?  This would help us write a regex or other logic to extract them from the URLs.

Comment: Hi, have just found that rules https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/#media_redirect

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen think the shortcode is always after the /p/

Comment: @Spawnrad Could you add the pattern from the link to the question?

Comment: @Thefourthbird i add the instagram pattern : /p/shortcode/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took you original query and added a `.*` bafore the `\/p\/`

This gave a query of 
`^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:instagram\.com.*\/p\/)([\d\w\-_]+)(?:\/)?(\?.*)?$`

This would be simpler assuming the username always follows the `/p/`

`^(?:.*\/p\/)([\d\w\-_]+)`

Answer (score 1):

You could prepend an optional `(?:\/\w+)?` non capturing group.

Note that `\w` also matches `_` and `\d` so the capturing group could be updated to `([\w-]+)` and the forward slash in the non capturing group might also be written as just `/`

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:instagram\.com(?:\/\w+)?\/p\/)([\w-]+)(?:\/)?(\?.*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nO4vdd/2)

You don't have to escape the backslashes if you use a different delimiter than `/`. Your pattern might look like:

```
^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:instagram\.com(?:/\w+)?/p/)([\w-]+)/?(\?.*)?$
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression might also work:

```
^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?instagram\.com\/[^\/]+(?:\/[^\/]+)?\/([^\/]{11})\/.*$
```

---

#### Test

```
$re = '/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?instagram\.com\/[^\/]+(?:\/[^\/]+)?\/([^\/]{11})\/.*$/m';
$str = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BxKRx5CHn5i/
https://www.instagram.com/p/BxKRx5CHn5i/?utm_source=ig_share_sheet&igshid=znsinsart176
https://www.instagram.com/p/BxKRx5CHn5i/
https://www.instagram.com/username/p/BxKRx5CHn5i/';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    var_export($match[1]);
}
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/AxF1YB/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you aren't simply trusting `/p/` as the marker before the substring, you can use this pattern which will consume one or more of the directories before your desired substring.

Notice that `\K` restarts the fullstring match, and effectively removes the need to use a capture group -- this means a smaller output array and a shorter pattern.

Choosing a pattern delimiter like `~` which doesn't occur inside your pattern alleviates the need to escape the forward slashes.  This again makes your pattern more brief and easier to read.

If you do want to rely on the `/p/` substring, then just add `p/` before my `\K`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aL2R7))

```
$strings = [
    "https://www.instagram.com/p/BxKRx5CHn5i/",
    "https://www.instagram.com/p/BrODg5XHlE6/?utm_source=ig_share_sheet&igshid=znsinsart176",
    "https://www.instagram.com/p/BxKRx5CHn5i/",
    "https://www.instagram.com/username/p/BxE5PpZhoa9/",
    "https://www.instagram.com/username/p/BxE5PpZhoa9/#look=overhere"
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo preg_match('~(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?instagram\.com(?:/[^/]+)*/\K\w+~', $string , $m) ? $m[0] : '';
    echo " (from $string)\n";
}
```

Output:

```
BxKRx5CHn5i (from https://www.instagram.com/p/BxKRx5CHn5i/)
BrODg5XHlE6 (from https://www.instagram.com/p/BrODg5XHlE6/?utm_source=ig_share_sheet&igshid=znsinsart176)
BxKRx5CHn5i (from https://www.instagram.com/p/BxKRx5CHn5i/)
BxE5PpZhoa9 (from https://www.instagram.com/username/p/BxE5PpZhoa9/)
BxE5PpZhoa9 (from https://www.instagram.com/username/p/BxE5PpZhoa9/#look=overhere)
```

If you are implicitly trusting the `/p/` as the marker and you *know* that you are dealing with instagram links, then you can avoid regex and just cut out the 11-character-substring, 3-characters after the marker.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aoAbf))

```
$strings = [
    "https://www.instagram.com/p/BxKRx5CHn5i/",
    "https://www.instagram.com/p/BrODg5XHlE6/?utm_source=ig_share_sheet&igshid=znsinsart176",
    "https://www.instagram.com/p/BxKRx5CHn5i/",
    "https://www.instagram.com/username/p/BxE5PpZhoa9/",
    "https://www.instagram.com/username/p/BxE5PpZhoa9/#look=overhere"
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $pos = strpos($string, '/p/');
    if ($pos === false) {
        continue;
    }
    echo substr($string, $pos + 3, 11);
    echo " (from $string)\n";
}
```

(Same output as previous technique)